# SPSS repeat a task on many files

Tags: automation, macros, spss

I would like to achieve the following:
For each of the 100 datasets (saved in .sav), **1)** open file, **2)** add a variable called 'Day' to it and populate it with number. so file1 will have 1 under 'Day', file2 will have 2 under 'Day' and so on (see figure1 below).  **3)** Select  the rows that has Status = 0. and **4)** save it in a format of ABC - Day xx - Female.sav
[figure1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JdmK.png)

Ultimately, I will have 100 separate files saved in ABC - Day(1 to 100) - Female.sav.

So far I have been doing them one by one, but I am wondering if there is a way to automate this process?
Here is my code so far:

```
***DAY 1***.
***open file***.
GET 
  FILE='ABC - Day 1 - Female_May 6, 2022_09.24.sav'. 
DATASET NAME DataSet1 WINDOW=FRONT.
***Drop a row of data***.
SELECT IF (Status=0).
***Add Day***.
COMPUTE DAY = 1.
EXECUTE.
***save file***.
SAVE OUTFILE='Testing\ABC - Day 1 - Female.sav'
  /COMPRESSED.

***DAY 2***.
***open file***.
GET 
  FILE='ABC - Day 2- Female_May 6, 2022_09.24.sav'. 
DATASET NAME DataSet1 WINDOW=FRONT.
***Drop a row of data***.
SELECT IF (Status=0).
***Add Day***.
COMPUTE DAY = 2.
EXECUTE.
***save file***.
SAVE OUTFILE='Testing\ABC - Day 2 - Female.sav'
  /COMPRESSED.

***DAY 3***.
***open file***.
GET 
  FILE='ABC - Day 3- Female_May 6, 2022_09.24.sav'. 
DATASET NAME DataSet1 WINDOW=FRONT.
***Drop a row of data***.
SELECT IF (Status=0).
***Add Day***.
COMPUTE DAY = 3.
EXECUTE.
***save file***.
SAVE OUTFILE='Testing\ABC - Day 3 - Female.sav'
  /COMPRESSED.
```

I have read that for repetitive commands like this you could write a Macro, but I couldn't find good resources on this? If anyone has any suggestions or pointers, I would greatly appreciat that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following macro will do what you need - it iterates over the `!day` parameter and performs the sequence you described.

Note - skipped lines in the macro are necessary - do not delete.

```
define !dofiles ()
!do !day=1 !to 100
***open file***.
!concat("GET  FILE='ABC - Day ", !day, " - Female_May 6, 2022_09.24.sav'. ") 

***Drop a row of data***.
SELECT IF (Status=0).
***Add Day***.
COMPUTE DAY = !day .
***save file***.
!concat("SAVE OUTFILE='Testing\ABC - Day ", !day , " - Female.sav'   /COMPRESSED. ")

dataset close all.
!doend
!enddefine.

* Now that the macro is defined you can call it using it's name.
!dofiles .
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! Worked like magic. Just want to clarify and see if I understand this correctly: The key to looping ACROSS files is to define an iterator and include the GET FILE command in the macro? I am hoping to adapt this to future syntax that involves repetitive commands like these.

Comment: In general you got it. There are other ways to do this - with Python code blocks for example, but in this case a macro seems like the simplest solution. In any case this was a nice first question, and you are welcome to ask more questions for your futur adaptations :)